# Corrigir parênteses desbalanceados

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Dada uma string preenchida com um número qualquer de parênteses, encontre o número mínimo de parênteses a serem incluídos na string, de maneira que ela seja válida.

Exemplos:

- Input `"(()()"` deve retornar: `1 - "(()())"`
- Input `"((("` deve retornar: `3 - "((()))"`
- Input `"())()"` deve retornar: `1 - "(())()"`

```js
function isBalanced(str) {
  var a = verifica(str)
  var i = 0

  if ( a ) {

    var toRepair,newStr

    toRepair = a == '(' ? ')' : '('

    console.log('str = ', str)

    do {
      newStr = str
      newStr = newStr.substring(0,i)+toRepair+newStr.substring(i)
      console.log( 'newStr = ', newStr)

      i += 1
    } while ( verifica(newStr)  )


    console.log('O certo é: ', newStr)


  } else {
    console.log('ta tudo certo')

  }

}

function verifica(str) {
  var a = str, b
  do { 
    b = a,
    console.log('b = ', b)
    a = a.replace(/\(\)/g, '')
  } while (a != b)

  console.log(a ? 'ta errado' : 'ta certo')

  return a
}



isBalanced('(()()')
```

https://repl.it/@Aterius/Corrigir-os-parentesis#index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa de regex pra isso. Uma maneira mais simples é contar os parênteses. Você itera pelos caracteres da string, e se encontrar um `(`, incrementa o contador, e se encontrar um `)`, decrementa.

Só tem um porém: se a string começar com `)` por exemplo, você não pode decrementar, senão o contador ficará negativo. Nesse caso você tem que considerar que faltou o `(` correspondente, então deve contabilizar 1 a mais para esse caso.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493222/112052) disse para simplesmente contar a quantidade de `(` e `)` e subtrair um do outro, mas e se a string for `)(`? Nesse caso, se fizermos somente a contagem e subtrair, dará zero. Mas entendo que neste caso faltam 2 parênteses (um antes do `)` e outro depois do `(`), então teria que ser assim:

```js
function quantosParentesesFaltam(str) {
    var naoAbertos = 0, qtd = 0;
    for (var c of str) {
        if (c == '(') { // abriu um parênteses
            qtd++;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (qtd == 0) {
                // encontrei um ) sem o ( correspondente
                naoAbertos++;
            } else {
                // fechou o parênteses, diminui o contador pois está ok
                qtd--;
            }
        }
    }
    return qtd + naoAbertos;
}

console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam('(()()')); // 1
console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam('(((')); // 3
console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam('())()')); // 1
console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam(')(')); // 2
console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam(')))(')); // 4
console.log(quantosParentesesFaltam('(()())')); // 0
```

---

Agora se a ideia é contar **e** consertar a string, basta adaptar o caso acima para adicionar os parênteses que faltam na string:

```js
function conserta(str) {
    var balanceada = str;
    var naoAbertos = 0, qtd = 0;
    for (var c of str) {
        if (c == '(') { // abriu um parênteses
            qtd++;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (qtd == 0) {
                // encontrei um ) sem o ( correspondente
                naoAbertos++;
                // adiciona o ( no início
                balanceada = '(' + balanceada;
            } else {
                // fechou o parênteses, diminui o contador pois está ok
                qtd--;
            }
        }
    }
    // adiciona os ) que faltam
    for(var i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
        balanceada += ')';
    }
    return `${qtd + naoAbertos} - "${balanceada}"`;
}

console.log(conserta('(()()')); // 1 - "(()())"
console.log(conserta('(((')); // 3 - "((()))"
console.log(conserta('())()')); // 1 - "(())()"
console.log(conserta(')(')); // 2 - "()()"
console.log(conserta(')))(')); // 4 - "((()))()"
console.log(conserta('(()())')); // 0 - "(()())"
```

Basicamente, se encontrei um `)` sem o `(` correspondente (que é quando o caractere atual é `)` e o contador `qtd` é zero), eu sei que falta adicionar um `(` no início.

Depois, no final do primeiro `for`, o contador `qtd` terá a quantidade de `(` que não foram fechados, então basta adicionar essa mesma quantidade de `)` no final.

---

#### Até dá para usar regex

Embora eu ache as soluções acima **muito** mais simples, dá para usar regex.

Assumindo que a string tem somente os caracteres `(` e `)` (não há **nenhum outro** caractere diferente desses), uma ideia é procurar por pares de `()` (ou seja, um `(` seguido imediatamente por um `)`) e ir removendo-os da string, até que não sobre nenhum.

O que sobrar na string são os desbalanceados. Então se tiver algum `)` no início, é porque faltam adicionar `(` no começo, e se tiver `(` no fim, basta adicionar `)` no final.

Assim:

```js
function consertaComRegex(str) {
    var r = /\(\)/g;
    var s = str, tmp;
    // enquanto tiver () para ser removido, continua
    while ((tmp = s.replace(r, '')) != s) {
        s = tmp;
    }
    if (s.length == 0) {
        return `0 - "${str}"`;
    }
    // verifica se começa com um ou mais )
    var match = s.match(/^\)+/);
    if (match) { // adiciona os ( que faltam no início
        for(var i = 0; i < match[0].length; i++) str = '(' + str;
    }
    // verifica se termina com um ou mais (
    var match = s.match(/\(+$/);
    if (match) { // adiciona os ) que faltam no final
        for(var i = 0; i < match[0].length; i++) str += ')';
    }
    return `${s.length} - "${str}"`;
}

console.log(consertaComRegex('(()()')); // 1 - "(()())"
console.log(consertaComRegex('(((')); // 3 - "((()))"
console.log(consertaComRegex('())()')); // 1 - "(())()"
console.log(consertaComRegex(')(')); // 2 - "()()"
console.log(consertaComRegex(')))(')); // 4 - "((()))()"
console.log(consertaComRegex('(()())')); // 0 - "(()())"
```

Comment: Amigo, desculpe a ignorância. Olhando seu código eu entendi a parte de incremento e decremento. porém não entendi como ele sabe em qual posição deve acrescentar o parenteses, poderia me explicar por favor?

Comment: @DeElfos Adicionei uma explicação na resposta

Comment: muito obrigado! Agora compreendi!

Answer (score 0):

Sua questão não está totalmente clara. Em alguma situação é necessário reordenar os caracteres ou somente incluir novos?
No caso de você não ter que reordenar os caracteres mas somente saber quantos caracteres, esse problema pode ser resolvido utilizando uma abordagem diferente. Você pode contar quantos caracteres **'('** e quantos caracteres **')'** há na String e calcular a diferença entre eles.
Esse é o número de caracteres que precisam ser inseridos para tornar a String válida:

```
let numeroCaracteresInseridos = abs(contadorAbre - contadorFecha)
```

Comment: E se a string for `)(`? Eu entendo que nesse caso faltam 2 parênteses - um antes do `)` e outro depois do `(`  - então não basta contar, tem que considerar a ordem em que eles aparecem.

Comment: Na verdade está sim, a questão de ordem dos fatores é importante!